# browser back button and session state in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, back-button, browser-history

I am trying to handle a problem i have when the user clicks the browser back button.

1. If i do not disable caching the page is loaded from the cache. The problem is i have data saved in the session object and this data is not synchronized with the page display so i get errors when the user makes a further request on that page.
2. If i disable cache I get a "`Confirm Form Resubmission`" on chrome. This happens because interacting with asp.net pages uses post requests (in order to send the view state) so the browser is asking if it should resubmit the form.

Both possibilities are problematical for me.
What is the best way to handle this problem?

> Edit:

I wrote the answer i found below.
It seems to me to be a hack. If anyone has a better solution i'd be happy to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the method i found [here](http://monket.net/blog/2010/02/detecting-when-a-page-is-loaded-from-the-browser-cache/).

I wrote a cookie with the value of "0" on server side indicating the page was loaded from the server.
In javascript i check whether the cookie value is "0".
If the value is "0" I overwrite the cookie value to "1".
If the value is "1" I reload the page.